# Can't read a file parm in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

example :

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Parse CSV'){
            steps {
                script{
                    def fileToParse = readFile(params.FileLocation)
                }
                echo fileToParse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I configured the job from the GUI, the file location parameter is called `FileLocation`. I uploaded a file and tried to read it. When I try to access `params.FileLocation` it returns `null`, as if it doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the variable scope. You def the variable in the *script {}* block scope, then try to use it outside of it. One easy fix is to def the variable outside the *pipeline {}* block at the global level. Or, just use the params.FileLocation in your echo statement.

```
def fileToParse

pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Parse CSV'){
            steps {
                script{
                    fileToParse = readFile(params.FileLocation)
                }
                echo fileToParse
                echo params.FileLocation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

file param is not supported and it is removed from documentation as well.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413

Check available parameters: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters